# properties of alternating subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was wondering, is it true that if $Alt_n$ is an alternating subgroup of $Sym_n$ for $n>3$, $Alt_{n-i}\leq Alt_n$ for all $i<n$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\le$ here?  Does that mean that $Alt_{n-i} $ is a subgroup of $Alt_n$?

Comment: Yes! I do mean that.

Comment: More interesting is, that $S_n$ cannot be embedded into $A_{n+1}$, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65083/an-easy-proof-that-sn-does-not-embed-into-an1).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, in a strict sense.  A permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$ is not a permutation of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  However, there is a natural bijection between the set of permutations of the former, and the set of permutations of the latter that fix $4$.  Similarly, there is a natural bijection between $Alt_{n-i}$ and a subgroup of $Alt_n$, namely those permutations that fix $(n-i+1), (n-i+2),\ldots, n$.

Comment: I guess that is what I was looking for then... I meant, is it true then that there exists a subgroup of $Alt_{n}$ that is isomorphic to $Alt_{n-i}$ for all $i<n$?

Comment: Yes, a natural one, as described above.  Just fix the other elements.

Comment: It is clear, but it should still be stated, that every permutation in $Alt_n$ in the range of the bijection is an even permutation: i.e. it really is in $Alt_n$ and not just in $Sym_n$.

Comment: In fact, there are *several* such isomorphisms besides the "obvious" one, as you can make $n$ distinct isomorphs of $S_{n-1}$ inside $S_n$, by choosing different elements to be "fixed".